# Citrus Framework - How to trace and print the Response from Server

Tags: citrus-framework

I am using CitrusFramework for Rest API testing.I have scanned through the method but didn't get anything which can print the Response Stack Trace.

Regards
Bidhu

Comment: As much as I'd like to help you, I don't understand your question. Can you please add more details? Which method have you "scanned" through? What do you mean by "scanned"? What kind of response stack trace do you expect? Please post a concrete example of what you would like to see from Citrus.

Comment: I have a Test case for Get method where i wanted to Trace the Response message in the Eclipse Console, Do we have any inbuilt method for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to analyze the details of a HTTP response you get from a server under test.

## Setting Debug Mode

First, you need to set Citrus' log level to `DEBUG`. You can find an example on how this can be achieved in the Citrus `sample-http` repository:
https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/blob/master/sample-http/src/test/resources/log4j.properties

There are two important things to note:

1. `log4j.logger.com.consol.citrus=DEBUG`: Sets all Citrus classes to log in debug mode
2. `log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender` will append the logs to the console log, so it appears in your console.

Unless you already have a `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` in your project, you can simply copy `log4j.properties` from the example to your project into `src/test/resources/`.
Otherwise, you need to add the entries to your existing Log4J settings.

A different more sophisticated example can be found in the `sample-flightbooking` (using Log4Js XML format):
https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/blob/master/sample-flightbooking/src/test/resources/log4j.xml

## Finding the Traces in the Logs

If you have Citrus set to `DEBUG` then you will find something similar to the following in you log:

```
18:10:55,743 DEBUG ingClientInterceptor| Sending Http request message
18:10:55,744 DEBUG   Logger.Message_OUT| GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
Accept:text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length:0


18:10:56,096 DEBUG ingClientInterceptor| Received Http response message
18:10:56,096 DEBUG    Logger.Message_IN| HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:Mon, 07 Aug 2017 16:10:52 GMT
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Connection:keep-alive
Set-Cookie:__cfduid=d5ca2a6c467ea8aa495ab766d86e16eef1502122252; expires=Tue, 07-Aug-18 16:10:52 GMT; path=/; domain=.typicode.com; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By:Express
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Cache-Control:public, max-age=14400
Pragma:no-cache
Expires:Mon, 07 Aug 2017 20:10:52 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
Etag:W/"124-yiKdLzqO5gfBrJFrcdJ8Yq0LGnU"
Via:1.1 vegur
CF-Cache-Status:HIT
Server:cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY:38ab822e68527d08-MUC

{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

As you can see, you will find the whole HTTP trace in the logs.

If you need the real HTTP trace, which does not depend on any logging framework, then the most reliant way is to use a sniffer tool like Wireshark or TCPMon. I have used TCPMon (even if it is no longer supported) to debug sometimes.

Yet another way is to add an interceptor to your HTTP client, like described in the [Citrus documentation](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#http-client-interceptors). This is how Citrus' `LoggingClientInterceptor` logs the HTTP trace which you can see in the example.

Comment: Thanks much for the Reply, However i have added the "LoggingClientInterceptor " to my Application Context but still i am not getting the Log in the console. Can you please help me on how to Put the Citrus as "Debug".

Comment: Maybe you have misunderstood me. You don't need to add the `LoggingClientInterceptor` to your context. It is used by Citrus' HTTP client by default. I meant that you could add a custom one if you wanted to. As for the debug option I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Much gucce, I can trace the Log in the Console.

Comment: @bidhujena Great! Can you please upvote my response then?

Comment: @bidhujena Please mark the response as correct if it answered your question. Thanks!